# C# Multiple classes using same TcpClient

Tags: c#, resources, tcpclient

I have been reading around and using the website for quite a long time. I'm a newbie programmer as I come from another engineering discipline but I have to program simple applications at work.

Now I am stuck with the following problem:

I use the System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient class to communicate to a test instrument over TCP IP. The InstrumentControl class I have implemented has a private property which is an instance of the TcpClient class (let's call it instHandler), and all necessary methods to write and query data from the test instrument. So far, communication with the instrument works fine when I use the InstrumentControl class.

Now my problem is, I want to have several and separate classes to differentiate e.g. from InstrumentConfiguration and InstrumentCapture. These two could be different classes that make use of the same resource (the TCP IP port), available from the InstrumentControl class.

How would you solve that problem? The diagram of my project would look like:

- InstrumentControl.cs :: uses the TcpClient class to communicate to the instrument
- InstrumentConfiguration.cs :: uses the InstrumentControl class to configure the instrument (in particular the instHandler property)
- InstrumentCapture.cs :: uses the InstrumentControl class (in particular the instHandler property)

The problem is that if I use e.g. inheritance, then when I call the constructor of InstrumentConfiguration and InstrumentCapture, both attempt to connect to the TCP IP, which is not possible. How can my two classes share the same instance of the TcpClient class, or the InstrumentControl class?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Dependency Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323705(v=vs.100).aspx) is the idea you're looking for.

Comment: Did you consider adding constructors that latch onto an existing instance of InstrumentControl provided by the caller?

Comment: Hello ext0, thank you for your response. Could you extend it a bit more? I can't find any resources that solve what I am looking for